# Is there a way to force a specific evaluation order of function arguments?

Tags: c++, c++14, order-of-execution, unspecified-behavior

I understand that when I call a function such as

```
a(b(),c());
```

then the behavior of this may be undefined in <= C++14, and unspecified in >= C++17, in the sense that it is up to the compiler to determine whether to evaluate `b` or `c` first.

I would like to know the best way to force an evaluation order. I will be compiling as C++14.

The thing that immediately comes to mind is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int count = 5;
auto increment(){
    return count++;
}

template <typename A, typename B>
auto diff(A && a, B && b){
   return a - b;
}

int main() {
    auto && a = increment();
    auto && b = increment();
    auto c = diff(a,b);
}
```

Am I in undefined behavior land? Or is this how one is "supposed" to force evaluation order?

Comment: why do you think there could be ub?

Comment: I dunno. I hear many people complain about the ub with C++14 in the first example. But the approach I outline seems obvious to me, so I feel like there is something that I am missing.

Comment: Like some gottcha that I should be aware of, specifcally when saving the `auto && a = bar();` and then passing that to another function.

Comment: You are right. I guess if I had used a diff instead of a sum, then it would be ub. That is what I meant.

Comment: @Peter even if a global variable is used (read and/or written) by the two functions, the behavior would not be undefined, but just unspecified.

Comment: @Peter *Expressions* can be evaluated in an interleaved manner up to C++14, but even then each function invocation in an argument must be executed as a whole. It has *never* been the case that functions could have been executed interleaved or in parallel. See rule 11 in the [Rules section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (and rule 4 in the sequence point rules further down).

Comment: @bremen_matt: diff doesn't make a difference (pun intended), it is still just unspecified, not UB. There is no difference between standard versions in this regard, this was always unspecified.

Comment: Is there anything in the standard that would stop a C++14 compiler from choosing randomly at runtime whether to evaluate b or c first in the expression a(b(),c())? That seems to be undefined behavior.

Comment: I may just be confusing unspecified and undefined

Comment: @bremen_matt: Undefined means *anything* can happen (the standard doesn't specify what should happen). Unspecified means `b()` and then `c()`, or `c()` and then `b()`. One of them will happen. It is not specified, which.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The semi-colon that separates statements imposes a "happens before" relation.
`auto && a = increment()` must be evaluated first. It is guaranteed. The returned temporary will be bound to the reference `a` (and its lifetime extended) before the second call to `increment`.

There is no UB. This is *the* way to force an evaluation order.

The only gotcha here is if `increment` returned a reference itself, then you'd need to worry about lifetime issues. But if there was no lifetime issues, say if it returned a reference to `count`, there still would not be UB from the imposed evaluation of `a` and then `b`.

Answer (score 17):

Here's another way to force the evaluation order, using a `std::initializer_list`, which has a guaranteed left-to-right order of evaluation:

```
#include <numeric> // for accumulate
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
auto diff(std::initializer_list<T> args)
{
   return std::accumulate(args.begin(), args.end(), T(0), std::minus<>{});
}

const auto result = diff({increment(), increment()});
```

This restricts you to objects of the same type, and you need to type additional braces.

Comment: Not sure but I think you can get this to work with different types via tuples: `std::apply(func, std::tuple<funcsargs>({__VA_ARGS__}));`

Comment: apply is C++17 I think

Comment: @bremen_matt Thanks for the edit for consistency with the question. Minor nitpick: `std::accumulate` does `std::plus<>` by default, so we need to pass a `std::minus<>` instance to do the actual subtraction.

Comment: Oops. Slipped through the cracks. I changed the example slightly so that it is easier for others to understand why order of execution is important. In the previous example, it actually didn't matter.